# Tuples in where condition

Tags: linq, f#, equality

Given that in F#

> Tuples have an automatically defined equality operation

and therefore

```
let myQueryable = [| (1, 1); (2,2)|].AsQueryable()
let check =
    query {
        for x in myQueryable do
        } |> Seq.where(fun x -> x = (2,2))
```

is `{(2,2)}`, then why

```
let check =
        query {
            for x in myQueryable do
            where(x = (2, 2))
            }
```

is `Empty`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have `System.Linq` open.

The following returns `(2,2)` for me in both cases:

```
//open System
//open System.Linq

let myQueryable = [| (1, 1); (2,2) |] //.AsQueryable()
let check =
    query {
            for x in myQueryable do
            select x
          } |> Seq.where(fun x -> x = (2,2))

check //val it : seq<int * int> = seq [(2, 2)]
let check' =
        query {
            for x in myQueryable do
            where (x = (2, 2)) 
            select x
            }

check' //val it : seq<int * int> = seq [(2, 2)]
```

So within an `IQueryable` this structural equality doesn't hold. I don't know if it's because of the IQueryable type, i.e. it becomes reference equality, or `where` gets redefined, or a possible bug.

Comment: yes, it is by C# -> F# **interop**: C# tuples get automatically compiled to F# tuples and viceversa

Answer (score 1):

It seems a compatibility issue between C# `System.Tuple` and F# reference tuples.

It is interesting that the compatibility issue seems to be solved between C# 7 and F# 4.1 with the new `ValueTuple` equivalent to F# struct tuples.

```
let myQueryableNew = [| ValueTuple.Create(1, 1); ValueTuple.Create(2,2) |].AsQueryable()
let resultFSharp1 =
    query {
            for x in myQueryableNew do
          } |> Seq.where(fun x -> x = ValueTuple.Create(2,2))

let resultFSharp2 =
        query {
            for x in myQueryableNew do
            where (x.Equals(ValueTuple.Create(2, 2))) 
            }
```

Btw, notice also that the new type has a more coherent default (in case of this related [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/3845))

```
let testDefault =
        query {
            for x in myQueriable1 do
            where (x.Equals(ValueTuple.Create(1, 2))) 
            select x
            headOrDefault
            }
```